# How to configure the Dynamics CRM 2011 Email Router to delete processed e-mails

Tags: email, dynamics-crm-2011

**Current Situation:**

I'm using an incoming e-mail configuration profile pointing to an ExchangeOnline server and using the Exchange web services (EWS). Incoming email is imported into CRM into a queue. All is configured well, the access test passes and the received emails get successfully into the CRM queue etc. So far so good.

**Question:**

I want the router to delete successfully processed emails from the Exchange mailbox.

**What I already tried:**

The email router configuration tool doesn't show an option for this to configure in the GUI. So I took a look at the 'Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EmailAgent.xml' file and found the `<DeleteEmails>false</DeleteEmails>` option. Changing it's value to `true` should do the trick, I thought. But as soon as the email router does another run, my changed value is reverted back to `false` again. I tried stopping the service and modify the XML again, but as soon as the service is restarted, again my change is undone. How can I get this value to stay on `true`? I found one article on the internet mentioning almost the same problem with a the CRM 4 email router and a POP3 mailbox, but that was fixed in some rollup for CRM 4. But now I have the same issue on a CRM 2011 server.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this discussion thread](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/105388.aspx#.Ud8XXkHYJWU) on the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Community forum, it isn't possible. Deleting e-mails after being processed by the email router only works for forward mailboxes.

Answer (score 0):

CRM can delete emails from a mailbox if it is using forward mailbox. You can achieve this by setting rules in your mailboxes to forward emails to the forwarding mailbox and delete them from the original mailbox.  CRM will then download and delete the emails from the forwarding mailbox.